# PHP - Get range either side of integer

Tags: php

In PHP, I am getting a range like this...

```
$number = range(0,50,10);
```

This is working, but now I am trying to modify it so that given a number, it will get the range 5 digits either side of that number.

So, for example, given the number 25, I would like...

```
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

To further slightly complicate things, I would only like these numbers to be positive, so if the start number was 3, then it would only get the range 1-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just subtract and add to the number in the center. Use the `max()` function to restrict the beginning to at least 1.

```
$n = 25;
$numbers = range(max(1, $n-5), $n+5)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`max()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) will help you out here.

```php
$width = 5; // Width of your range
$center = 3; // Center of your range

$r = range(max(1, $center-$width), $center+$width);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
for ($i = $number - 5; $i <= $number + 5; $i++) {
  if ($i > 0) {
    return $i;
  } else {
    return "negative";
  }
}
```

I am new to PHP and not entirely sure if that will work